# Constructor taking an auto_ptr

Tags: c++, initialization, auto-ptr

I want to write a C++ class with a constructor which takes an `auto_ptr` as its argument so that I could initialize class instances from `auto_ptr`s to another instance:

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
  A() {}
  A(std::auto_ptr<A> other) {}
};

std::auto_ptr<A> create()
{
  return std::auto_ptr<A>(new A());
}

void foo()
{
  A x = create();
  // A y ( create() );    // works
}
```

Compiling this code with `g++ -c test.cpp` on gcc 4.6 yields the following error messages:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void foo()’:
test.cpp:17:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::auto_ptr<A>::auto_ptr(std::auto_ptr<A>)’
test.cpp:17:16: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/auto_ptr.h:260:7: note: std::auto_ptr<_Tp>::auto_ptr(std::auto_ptr_ref<_Tp>) [with _Tp = A]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/auto_ptr.h:260:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::auto_ptr<A>’ to ‘std::auto_ptr_ref<A>’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/auto_ptr.h:125:9: note: std::auto_ptr<_Tp>::auto_ptr(std::auto_ptr<_Tp1>&) [with _Tp1 = A, _Tp = A]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/auto_ptr.h:125:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::auto_ptr<A>’ to ‘std::auto_ptr<A>&’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/auto_ptr.h:112:7: note: std::auto_ptr<_Tp>::auto_ptr(std::auto_ptr<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = A, std::auto_ptr<_Tp> = std::auto_ptr<A>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/backward/auto_ptr.h:112:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::auto_ptr<A>’ to ‘std::auto_ptr<A>&’
test.cpp:7:3: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘A::A(std::auto_ptr<A>)’
```

However, if I use the syntax `A y (create());` to create my object, it works.

I want to know why this happens and if there is anything I can do to work around it.

**EDIT:** I will also point out that if I change the constructor signature to

```
  A(const std::auto_ptr<A>& other) {}
```

then everything works beautifully, however this doesn't take ownership of the `auto_ptr` and thus doesn't have the semantics that I want.

**EDIT 2:** If I do the same thing with an assignment operator, i.e.,

```
A& operator=( std::auto_ptr<A> other) {}
```

then I can do

```
A x;
x = create();
```

Why?

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::auto_ptr`, `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated.

Comment: Considering `create()` returns an `auto_ptr` wouldn't it have to be: `std::auto_ptr<A> x = create();`?

Comment: @GManNickG: I don't have the luxury to be able to use C++11, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are only allowed *one* implicit, user-defined conversion. Constructing an `auto_ptr` from another one already involves the implicit conversion through an auxiliary `auto_ptr_ref` class, and so you cannot implicitly construct your own class from an `auto_ptr`.

By using direct initialization, one of the conversions is *explicit*, and only one implicit user-defined conversion remains, which is fine.

To "work around" the lack of implicit conversion, you can either modify your constructor to take the `auto_ptr` by (non-const) reference, or migrate everything to `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I didn't know about the "only one implicit conversion" rule. The dark corners of C++. Is there an online source for this?

Comment: @eriatarka84: It's a fairly sensible rule if you think about it. If there's more than one conversion needed, there's no way in general to decide which chain of conversions is "the right one". Any good introductory book should describe implicit conversions.

Comment: That's funny, I've been using C++ for more than 15 years and yet I don't know all the stuff that's in an introductory book. I wonder if that says more about me or the language.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
A(std::auto_ptr<A>& other)
              //  ^ Note the reference!
{
    // Assign interned auto_ptr member here, which you definitely should have
}
```

Comment: That won't work, you can't bind temporaries (as the one returned from `create()`) to non-const references.

Comment: I've been just talking about the compiler errors mentioned in particular. There are other bugs in the OP's code yes!

Comment: Or flaws. To declare the `create()` method returning a `std::auto_ptr`, by value, to have no member to intern created auto_ptr' s, to have such method at public scope all, etc. Ah' sorry, you are the OP actually, didn't notice that.

Comment: `create()` is a function, not a method. And how else would you return an `auto_ptr` but by value?

Comment: That simply doesn't work for `std::auto_ptr`, because it's not possible to create it from a const copy itself! It want's to change ownership of the interned pointer. You might trying to do trickery using `std::autp_ptr::release()` but I don't recommend to do so.

Comment: @KerrekSB Explains this much better than me technically. But leads to the same result.

Comment: I think you didn't read the code carefully. The `auto_ptr` in the `create()` function is created from a new `A` instance, which is a standard usage pattern for `auto_ptr`. Such functions are sometimes called sources.

Comment: I did read your code, it does work for other cases, but not for construction!